# how to join on if one timestamp lies between two other timestamps in snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have 2 tables in snowflake as follows:

1. Table1:Player session( PlayerID, Session start timestamp, Session
   End timestamp)-- total 5013 rows
2. Table2:Player signup (PlayerID, Signup Timestamp )--total 283 rows

I only want the rows from the first table where signup timestamp(from table2) is in between 'session start timestamp' and 'session end timestamp' of table1 .

How can I join these two tables in such a way in Snowflake?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried joining them?

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t2.signup between t1.session_start and t1.session_end;
```

Comment: I did not want to join on playerid but that second argument (t2.signup between t1.session_start and t1.session_end) helped. Thanks a lot!